# any way to remove index.php without using htaccess file in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to remove `index.php` in URL of my project

i just opened CodeIgniter folder in `htdocs` and pasted this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [QSA,L] 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: no, there us not

Comment: Removing this isn't a codeigniter function, it's a web server function. It has to be done through the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file), you must be added following code to **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```